# JMeter Post API calls fails with validation errors

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a post api which passes string body that contains name in polish characters.
When execute this Post API its says name is not valid(as this is not matching name in system).

For the same API when i pass name in english it works without any errors.

Do we need to pass any specific header for this language. Appreciate if any one can help.

Thanks,
Anil

Answer (score 0):

I believe your application developers should be able to help more than random people from the Internet.

My expectation is that it should be sufficient to send the request in the corresponding [character set](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.4), for example `UTF-8`

It can be provided via `Content encoding` input of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults))

As you can see, Polish diacritics can be normally passed via HTTP Request sampler:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help it is working after i used UTF-8 in coding. Your awesome. appreciate your help. You saved my day